# Using Liferay's service builder to access existing tables in the database

Tags: liferay

I am writing a portlet that needs to read from a set of tables in the liferay database created by a different service builder portlet.

I tried just duplicating the service.xml and building the service and all I get for my troubles is :

**BeanLocator has not been set**

Is there a simple way of writing a second portlet that can get to these existing tables and can service builder be configured to do this rather than trying to re-create what is already there?

I do not want to add this into the original portlet if at all possible as these tables are holding information that a variety of other portlets may need to access and having a vast number of portlets in one deployment will make maintenance a headache.

Answer (score 8):

For accessing the same tables of a service in different portlets, do not recreate the services in each one. Instead, create the service in one portlet and copy its `docroot/WEB-INF/lib/<pluginmame>-portlet-service.jar` to the `docroot/WEB-INF/lib/` directory of the other portlets. Let us see an example.

Suppose you have the following `service.xml` in a portlet called `person-portlet`:

```
<service-builder package-path="br.com.seatecnologia.stackoverflow.person">
    <author>brandizzi</author>
    <namespace>StackOverflowPerson</namespace>

    <entity name="Person" local-service="true" remote-service="false">
        <column name="personId" type="long" primary="true" />

        <column name="name" type="String" />
        <column name="age" type="int" />
    </entity>
</service-builder>
```

You generate the services and use it in the original portlet, as usual. For example, you can create a JSP with a form for person registration and person listing:

```
<%@page import="br.com.seatecnologia.stackoverflow.person.service.PersonLocalServiceUtil"%>
<%@page import="br.com.seatecnologia.stackoverflow.person.model.Person"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui" %>

<portlet:actionURL name="addPerson" var="url" />

<aui:form action="<%= url %>" name="fm" method="POST">
<aui:fieldset>
<aui:input name="name" />
<aui:input name="age" />
<aui:button type="submit" />
</aui:fieldset>
</aui:form>

<ul>
    <% for (Person person : PersonLocalServiceUtil.getPersons(-1, -1)) { %>
    <li><%= person.getName() %> : <%= person.getAge() %></li>
    <% } %>
</ul>
```

Now, suppose you need another portlet, some kind of Hello World which presents a greeting message to all registered persons. You create a new portlet plugin - called, let us say, `multiple-hello-portlet` - and then copies the file `person-portlet-service.jar` from the `person-portlet/docroot/WEB-INF/lib` directory to `multiple-hello-portlet/docroot/WEB-INF/lib`. *If you have both* portlets deployed in the same portal_, you can use the services created for `person-portlet` in the `multiple-hello-portlet` too. For example, your `multiple-hello-portlet` can have the following JSP *and there is no need of reimplementing services*:

```
<%@page import="br.com.seatecnologia.stackoverflow.person.service.PersonLocalServiceUtil"%>
<%@page import="br.com.seatecnologia.stackoverflow.person.model.Person"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet" prefix="portlet" %>

<% for (Person person :  PersonLocalServiceUtil.getPersons(-1, -1)) { %>
    <div class="portlet-msg-info">
        Hello, <%= person.getName() %>!
        You are <%= person.getAge() %> years old.
    </div>
<% } %>
```

I created two runnable portlets with these examples, that you can find in [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/brandizzi/shared-service-builder-example/src).

Comment: I had actually tried this with no success, the difference is I am accessing the methods from within a java class rather than the JSP.

Comment: @PaulGilfedder The effect would be the same with this approach if it was on JSP or Java so you may have an issue somewhere else. Are you using an IDE? If so does it give any errors?

Comment: @PaulGilfedder that is strange. What is version of the Liferay you are using? Liferay EE ou CE? Is there some SP on it?

Comment: We are using a heavily modified version of 5.2.3

Comment: I tried this approach again in a brand new Liferay 5.2.3 and it worked flawlessly. I would bet the problem may be in your customizations (you are using EXT environment, right?). Unfortunately, `BeanLocator has not been set` is an absolutely useless error message because it happens all the time, for all the reasons that can be in any point of the code. Sorry, I cannot help anymore from this point :(

Comment: Thanks @bradizzi, I am personally not using EXT, but EXT has been used to modify the system and I suspect that it has nudged something.

Answer (score 2):

By running the service-builder, it generate a jar-File for access from other portlets.

> By default the generated service api jar will be bundled inside the portlet war file. But if you want other applications to access your services then the service api jar file needs to be there in the server classpath. You can do that by changing the preference which can be accessed by clicking on "Preferences" button. (Fig: 6)

from: http://www.liferay.com/de/about-us/news/-/blogs/2506216/maximized

Answer (score 1):

You could put the service builder stuff in a Liferay Hook Plugin of its own, that the other portlets depend on (aka plugin needs to be deployed for portlets to work).

You could also use an EXT plugin instead of a hook which would extend Liferay with your custom service builder stuff.

Comment: It's not advised to use EXT plugins if you can possibly avoid it. In this case it's easily avoidable by having the produced {portletname}-portlet-service.jar from the first portlet on the classpath of the second portlet as Brandizzi explains.

Comment: You have a point regarding the EXT plugins, as they are very hard to deploy/undeploy/redeploy, and are best avoid unless there's no other Liferay plugin type that suits your need.